# How can I prevent arguments to `xargs` from being prefixed with spaces?

Tags: xargs

I have extracted an archive whose contents are not stored in a sub-directory into a directory with filled with other files and is now cluttered and confusing.

To fix this I have extracted the archive into a new empty directory and want to use the directory listing there to delete the files from first directory which got mixed up. The files were originally extracted into the '/usr/src/packages' directory and the new directory is `~/Programs/DBeaver`.

```
vfclists@hp01:~/Programs/DBeaver$ ls -l
total 216
-rw-r--r--  1 vfclists vfclists 48943 Oct 23 23:28 artifacts.xml
drwxr-xr-x  4 vfclists vfclists  4096 Oct 23 23:28 configuration
-rwxr-xr-x  1 vfclists vfclists 79058 Oct 23 22:58 dbeaver
-rw-r--r--  1 vfclists vfclists   206 Oct 23 23:28 dbeaver.ini
-rw-r--r--  1 vfclists vfclists  7919 Oct  9 14:05 dbeaver.png
drwxr-xr-x 23 vfclists vfclists  4096 Oct 23 23:28 features
-rwxr-xr-x  1 vfclists vfclists 35021 Oct 23 22:58 icon.xpm
drwxr-xr-x  2 vfclists vfclists  4096 Oct 23 23:28 licenses
drwxr-xr-x  4 vfclists vfclists  4096 Oct 23 23:28 p2
drwxr-xr-x  6 vfclists vfclists 20480 Oct 23 23:28 plugins
-rw-r--r--  1 vfclists vfclists  1791 Oct 23 23:28 readme.txt
vfclists@hp01:~/Programs/DBeaver$
```

So what I want to do is to pipe the output of `ls` to xargs but when I run the command the filename gets prepended with a space so I get test output like this.

```
vfclists@hp01:~/Programs/DBeaver$ ls  | xargs -n 1 echo rm /usr/src/packages/
rm /usr/src/packages/ artifacts.xml
rm /usr/src/packages/ configuration
rm /usr/src/packages/ dbeaver
rm /usr/src/packages/ dbeaver.ini
rm /usr/src/packages/ dbeaver.png
rm /usr/src/packages/ features
rm /usr/src/packages/ icon.xpm
rm /usr/src/packages/ licenses
rm /usr/src/packages/ p2
rm /usr/src/packages/ plugins
rm /usr/src/packages/ readme.txt
```

There is also the matter of distinguishing between directories and files, but I want to deal with this first.

UPDATE: It turns out that `rm -rf` works as well on files as on directories, to it doesn't really matter in this instance, so I simply have to replace `rm xxxx` with `rm -rf xxxx`

Comment: `rm -rf /usr/src/packages/ artifacts.xml` would remove `artifacts.xml` from the current directory, and the whole of `/usr/src/packages/`, including `/usr/src/packages/artifacts.xml` but everything else there too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `-I {}`, and `{}` at the place where you want the argument to appear:

```
xargs -I {} -n 1 echo rm /usr/src/packages/{}
```

(You can use something other than `{}`, `{}` is just very common.)

Without this, `xargs` simpy adds the input as additional arguments, so it's not a question of it adding spaces anywhere - the command receives the input as separate arguments.

You probably should use `find` instead of `ls`, especially if you want to distinguish files and directories.

Something like this to delete only files:

```
find . -type f -exec rm /usr/src/packages/{} \;
```